# How do I change a five by three gird to a three by five?

Tags: html, css

I have 15 images and I'm displaying them in a gird of five columns and three rows. Using media queries I'm reducing the size for different resolutions and want to change the layout at a certain resolution so having three per row instead of five.

I'm using floated divisions with a 20% width to do the layout but when I change the style to go to a 33% the first two rows work and then on the third row you get just one image at the right and then the other rows working as you would expect.

The code starts like this:

```
<div class="catalogue" style="display: inline-block;">
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item1" src="/images/item1.png" style="width: 200px; height: 160px;" /></div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item2" src="/images/item2.png" style="width: 204px; height: 160px;" /></div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item3" src="/images/item3.png" style="width: 200px; height: 160px;" /></div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item4" src="/images/item4.png" style="width: 199px; height: 160px;" /></div>
.
.
.
<div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item15" src="/images/item15.png" style="width: 199px; height: 160px;" /></div></div>
```

The initial styles are:

```
.catalogue{
    width: 1200px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 26px;
}
.catalogue-items{
    width: 20%;
    text-align: center; 
    float: left; 
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}
```

The style to change them are:

```
@media (max-width: 751px) {
   .catalogue{ width: 658px;}
   .catalogue-items { width: 33% !important;}
   .catalogue-items img{ width: 112px !important;}
}
```

If I inspect the element and remove the side on the image it shows correctly except that the images are larger than I want them. If I change the size of that style to the size of the image, it doesn't work.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try [**display: flex**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Why do I need to use flex? Surely that shouldn’t be a requirement.

Comment: Try `width: calc(100% / 3)` instead or `width:33.3333%`. Ideally you want the dimensions to be as close to 1/3 as possible.

Comment: Neither of those options made any difference.

Comment: This looks like it's working to me. What are you expecting? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Based on the fact that the code you provided is repetitive and works when repeated, I'm assuming you have a typo in one of your `div` class names on the third row somewhere.

Comment: As I explained, the first two row (six objects) display okay and then the seventh one displays on its own on the right before the eighth to the fifteenth showing correctly.

Comment: @leigero. Wouldn't that stop it working on five column layout too. I copied the code so it will be all the same. Also, why would it work when I remove the width?

Comment: I'll look through your fiddle and see if I an work it out. If I do, I'll let you know becuase you might want to post your comment as an answer so I can accerpt it and upvote it.

Comment: @RichardYoung added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-worked your code a bit in my example. The most important change is `min-height` followed by improvements in removing inline styles and prioritizing mobile styles first.

When you float items you'll want all the items to be the same height otherwise when they start a new row there is the potential for them to *"snag"* on a previous element if it taller than the others. When there is not longer enough room for a floated item to fit in a row it will move down to the next row and slide over.

[image]

```css
.catalogue {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 26px;
  width: 658px;
}
.catalogue-items {
  float: left; 
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  width: 33.33333%;
  min-height: 160px;
  text-align: center; 
}
.catalogue-items img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media ( min-width: 752px ) {
  .catalogue {
      width: 1200px; 
  }
  .catalogue-items {
      width: 20%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="catalogue">

    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item1" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item2" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item3" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item4" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item5" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>

    <!-- new row -->

    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item1" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item2" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item3" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item4" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item5" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>

    <!-- new row -->

    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item1" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item2" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item3" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item4" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item5" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>

    <!-- new row -->

    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item1" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item2" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item3" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item4" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>
    <div class="catalogue-items">
        <img alt="Item5" src="http://placehold.it/200x160px">
    </div>

</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ojoxyy3a/2/).

Comment: If I put a min-height on the catalogue-item division, would that sort the problem?

Comment: @RichardYoung that depends. If your `min-height` on `.catalogue-items` is always equal to the height of the tallest image, then **yes**. If you set `min-height` to `100px`and all of your images but a couple are `100px` and those couple of images are `125px` in height, then **no**. Those images would push outside of the defined `min-height` as it's defining a minimum and not a cap. If you want to use `min-height` make sure `min-height = tallest image` otherwise you'll have to use `height` or `max-height` or and `overflow[-x,-y]` property.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for this. I was virtually pulling my hair out and is usually such a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add min-height to .catalogue-items

Comment: That worked. As long at the minimum height was 92 pixels or more it worked. I don't understand why it worked. Could you please enlighten me?